# How to concatenate two columns with the same shape without loosing data?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on simple concatenate script using pandas. I have two tables. One is archive, a second is new. Before concatenate I need to add new column to second table, containing date of it's creation (which will be current date). What I'm struggling with is that concatenate function is losing new column with date of creation, when I try to export it's output to file.

I tried to change axis and sorting but nothing works. 
What is interesting, when I call the table with added creation date
everything looks ok.

```
hc = pd.read_csv
nhc = pd.read_csv

# Adding date column to new file
nhc['Report created on: '] = date.today()
nhc = nhc.set_index('Report created on: ').reset_index()

# Concatenate
union = [nhc, hc]
result = pd.concat(union, sort=False)
```

Comment: `pd.merge()` will help you perform the join

Comment: What's the meaning of nhc = nhc.set_index('Report created on: ').reset_index()?

Comment: After concatenate, what values will go in newly added column for `hc` dataframe? Do you want `hc` to have `nan` in new column, after concat?

Comment: @knagaev it restes index of 'Report created on: ' to move it to first column

Comment: @Parth I want all the data from hc and all the data from nhc, as union. Hc already has 1 column with date of creation, nhc don't have it. That's why I need to add it before concatenation.

Comment: @th00masml please, check index values before this statement and after with nhc.index.values
And how do you export result to a file?

Comment: Can you post `head()` for `hc`, `nhc` and `result` dataframes? It will help to understand.

Comment: @Parth unfortunately I can't but it was just syntax error. I rebuilded my script from beginning using your advises and now it works. Many Thanks!!